# Question on How @ and # String Trigger Works in Odoo Chatter?

Tags: odoo

Hope you guys doin well,

I'm curious about how can a certain string like `@` and `#` can trigger a popup of a user and channels in Odoo Chatter & Discuss. This chatter has `mail.thread` Models related to it but i can't seem to understand how is it possible to create my own custom trigger in chatter?

Is it belong to certain views and not in models?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [suggestion delimiters](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/models/composer_view/composer_view.js#L764) for the models used to update the suggestion list.

```
const suggestionDelimiters = ['@', ':', '#', '/'];
```

For example `@` is used to fetch partners ([mail.partner](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/models/partner/partner.js) model) matching a given search term. The `_updateSuggestionList` function will search the suggestions, sort them then will show ([update](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/models/composer_view/composer_view.js#L861)) the popup list

To add a new custom trigger, you need add the delimiter to the [suggestionDelimiters](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/models/composer_view/composer_view.js#L764) list and alter the [_computeSuggestionModelName](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15d90f368fb4b4e86580f2ca16c3eb6de47d20de/addons/mail/static/src/models/composer_view/composer_view.js#L584) function to return the related model, the model must be defined like the [mail.partner](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/models/partner/partner.js) model.

If you want to patch an existing model, check the following example (taken from the [hr](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15d90f368fb4b4e86580f2ca16c3eb6de47d20de/addons/mail/static/src/models/composer_view/composer_view.js#L584) module):

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import {
    registerInstancePatchModel,
    registerFieldPatchModel,
} from '@mail/model/model_core';
import { attr, one2one } from '@mail/model/model_field';


// Patch model
registerInstancePatchModel('mail.partner', 'hr/static/src/models/partner/partner.js', {

    async checkIsEmployee() {
        await this.async(() => this.messaging.models['hr.employee'].performRpcSearchRead({
            context: { active_test: false },
            domain: [['user_partner_id', '=', this.id]],
            fields: ['user_id', 'user_partner_id'],
        }));
        this.update({ hasCheckedEmployee: true });
    },

});

// Patch fields
registerFieldPatchModel('mail.partner', 'hr/static/src/models/partner/partner.js', {

    hasCheckedEmployee: attr({
        default: false,
    }),

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, and that is using the `/` or "command" popup. You can add your own item in the popup list and trigger any actions when a user selects your item from the popup.

1. Inherit from mail.channel

```
class MailChannel(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.channel'
```

2. Add a new method that starts with `_define_command_XXXXX`. This registers the item in the popup.

```
def _define_command_sample(self):
    return {'help': _('Here is some sample help')}
```

3. Add a new method that starts with `_execute_command_XXXXX`. This method is executed when the user uses your command.

```
def _execute_command_sample(self, **kwargs):
    # Send a "temporary" message to the user
    self._send_transient_message(self.env.user.partner_id, f"Hello! You just successfully used the /sample command. You typed {kwargs['body']}.")
```

Reference: [Github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/crm_livechat/models/mail_channel.py) where Odoo defines the `/lead` command

PS: The above is for Odoo V12.0 - V14.0. Odoo V15.0 works a bit different, but you can check [this](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/crm_livechat/models/mail_channel.py) and [this](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/crm_livechat/static/src/models/messaging_initializer/messaging_initializer.js) for how to do it.